# copy elasticsearch data from old index to new one

Tags: elasticsearch

When I try to reindex my data, I get a lot of errors (code: 500)

```
POST /_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "cwl-2021.01.06"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "mycwl1"
  }
}
```

How to avoid this?

```
{
  "index" : "mycwl1",
  "type" : "_doc",
  "id" : "35902178269278834817532895131701574511225501380192894978",
  "cause" : {
    "type" : "mapper_exception",
    "reason" : "timed out while waiting for a dynamic mapping update"
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

Comment: Did you create the same mapping on the new index first?

Comment: No. Is it really required? How to copy only mapping without data to the new index?

Comment: Reindex API does not copy your mappings. You can manage your mappings as described here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices.html#mapping-management

Comment: Found a good example: https://medium.com/@eyaldahari/reindex-elasticsearch-documents-is-easier-than-ever-103f63d411c

Comment: Isn't there an API for that? In mysql I can "create table x like y"!

Comment: You can use the Clone API f.e. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/indices-clone-index.html   
but your source index has to be read-only. Elasticsearch is not a database but a search engine many people misunderstand that. Are my suggestions sufficient for you? I will then make a proper answer out of it for others to find it useful.

Comment: Yes your suggestion is correct @x4k3p I need to create the mapping first. It is not clearly mentioned. And I wish there was an easier way to copy mapping.

Comment: @shantanuo Here's an elastic page on reindex that mentions the part about having to create a new index and copy the mappings and settings from the old index

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/reindex-upgrade-inplace.html